# как можно создавать массив из значения в обьекте

Tags: javascript

как можно получить новый массив состоящий из name например["dima", "Anna", "Denis"], и отдельный массив из lang ["javascript", "php", "html", "css", "python", "ruby"], пробовал через reduce Но видимо делаю гдето ошибку из за которой не выходит

```
function ready() {
    var employee = [
        {
            name: "Dima",
            lang: ["javascript", "php"],
            age: 21
        },
        {
            name: "Anna",
            lang: ["html", "css"],
            age: 26
        },
        {
            name: "Denis",
            lang: ["python", "ruby"],
            age: 18
        }
    ];
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первый способ - по новее.

```js
var employee = [{
    name: "Dima",
    lang: ["javascript", "php"],
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: "Anna",
    lang: ["html", "css"],
    age: 26
  },
  {
    name: "Denis",
    lang: ["python", "ruby"],
    age: 18
  }
];

var names = employee.filter(m => m.age > 19).map(m => m.name);
console.log(names);


var langs = employee.reduce((res, m) => res.concat(m.lang), []);
console.log(langs);
```

Второй способ - олдскульный.

```js
var employee = [{
    name: "Dima",
    lang: ["javascript", "php"],
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: "Anna",
    lang: ["html", "css"],
    age: 26
  },
  {
    name: "Denis",
    lang: ["python", "ruby"],
    age: 18
  }
];

var names = [];
var langs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
  var empl = employee[i];
  empl.age > 19 && names.push(empl.name);
  langs = langs.concat(empl.lang);
}

console.log(names);
console.log(langs);
```